# Transform rows to column based on group

Tags: sql-server

hi have a scenario where i have made a sql query output like this:

```
number  x1  y1  z1  x2  y2  z2  x3  y3  z3
 a       1  10  aa                        
 a       2   8  aa
 a       3   6  aa
 b       4   11 bb
 b       5   6  bb
```

Now I am stuck here: how to convert the above lines to this:

```
number  x1  y1  z1  x2  y2  z2  x3  y3  z3
 a       1  10  aa  2   8   aa   3   6  aa                    
 b       4  11  bb  5   6   bb
```

Each number can have up to 10 x_,y_,z_values (x1,y1,z1,...,x10,y10,z10)

So how can this be accomplished?

Comment: i have tried using update query on number to number to x1 not equals to x2 and so on but that didn't work.i tried it using pivot but i am not sure will pivot work for this case.

Comment: How does your source data look like? How is it structured?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what the logic behind this is, but yeah it can be done.

First, I used this to initialize more or less the same data you presented as a test set:

```
CREATE TABLE TESTTABLE (number varchar(5), x1 varchar(5), y1 varchar(5), z1 varchar(5)
     , x2 varchar(5), y2 varchar(5), z2 varchar(5), x3 varchar(5), y3 varchar(5), z3 varchar(5))

INSERT INTO TESTTABLE (number,x1,y1,z1)
VALUES ('a','1','10','aa')
    ,('a','2','8','aa')
    ,('a','3','6','aa')
    ,('b','4','11','bb')
    ,('b','5','6','bb')
```

Now for the queries.. If you're cool with hard coding the max number of columns, you can just go with something like this:

```
;WITH CTE AS 
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY number ORDER BY x1 asc) RN, *
    FROM TESTTABLE)
SELECT c.number, C.x1, C.y1, C.z1
    , C2.x1 as x2, C2.y1 as y2, C2.z1 as z2
    , C3.x1 as x3, C3.y1 as y3, C3.z1 as z3
FROM CTE C
LEFT JOIN CTE C2 ON C2.number = C.number AND C2.RN = 2
LEFT JOIN CTE C3 ON C3.number = C.number AND C3.RN = 3
WHERE C.RN=1
```

If however you want to dynamically display only the columns that have data, something like this would do the job (it's ugly, but my only concern was for it to work :) ).

```
DECLARE @TSQLHeader nvarchar(max) = '', @TSQLTrailer nvarchar(max) = '
FROM CTE C'

DECLARE @MaxCols INT = 
    (SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(*) CNT FROM TESTTABLE GROUP BY number ORDER BY CNT DESC)
    , @CurCol INT = 2

SELECT @TSQLHeader = 
';WITH CTE AS 
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY number ORDER BY x1 asc) RN, *
    FROM TESTTABLE)
SELECT c.number, C.x1, C.y1, C.z1'

WHILE @CurCol <= @MaxCols
BEGIN
    SELECT @TSQLHeader = @TSQLHeader+'
    , C'+CAST(@CurCol AS VARCHAR(5))+'.x1 as x'+CAST(@CurCol AS VARCHAR(5))+', C'+CAST(@CurCol AS VARCHAR(5))+'.y1 as y'+CAST(@CurCol AS VARCHAR(5))
    +', C'+CAST(@CurCol AS VARCHAR(5))+'.z1 as z'+CAST(@CurCol AS VARCHAR(5))
    SELECT @TSQLTrailer = @TSQLTrailer+'
LEFT JOIN CTE C'+CAST(@CurCol AS VARCHAR(5))+' ON C'+CAST(@CurCol AS VARCHAR(5))+'.number = C.number AND C'+CAST(@CurCol AS VARCHAR(5))+'.RN = '+CAST(@CurCol AS VARCHAR(5))

    SET @CurCol = @CurCol+1
END 

-- Combine the header and trailer, producing a finished script
SELECT @TSQLHeader = @TSQLHeader + @TSQLTrailer+'
WHERE C.RN=1'

EXEC sp_executesql @TSQLHeader
```

But of course, if there's anything you left out in your question, these would have to be changed quite drastically to accommodate anything different.

Comment: I believe the OP has mentioned that the first sample of data is actually a result he managed to get from writing a query. Now, he is trying to expland it to more than the first 3 columns (x1, y1, z1). In this case, I think it would be more important to know the source data and to build a solution on that, rather than on his intermediary result because, as you said, "would have to be changed quite drastically to accommodate anything different."

Comment: Yup agreed. But the only information we were provided was the result of his query, there was nothing else to go on, and for that, my response should provide a solution. Also, replacing the table references with a subquery containing his original query, should be an easy task.

Comment: Totally agree with you.